# Create sequence with sql result in it

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sequence like this

```
begin
 if :new."ID" is null then
     select to_number(sys_guid(),'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') into :new.id from dual;
  end if;
```

is there a way to set the ID to be the next upcoming ID in the table?

For example:

if my current last row ID is 5

I want the new.id to be 6, so when the INSERT executes then it would have ID of 6

Comment: Sequence? Do you mean trigger?

Comment: yes, sequence in side trigger

Comment: Which version of the database?

Comment: This is not possible with a sequence. A sequence gets you the next number; if you rollback, that number is lost and you'll have gaps. That doesn't matter with technical IDs, but you want your IDs gapless you say, so this method doesn't suffice.

Comment: What's wrong with the current code obtaining a sys_guid (which by definition should be unique?)  Maybe not syntactical error but what is wrong with the approach why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: Usually you'd use a sequence with a trigger (or an identity column instead when available - which uses a sequence behind the scenes) and a column that is big enough to guarantee that you won't have to recycle numbers someday. Thus you get increasing numbers. There can be gaps, but who cares; you can always use `ROW_NUMBER` to get contiguous numbers in the order of your ID column when you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDENTITY
column is now available on Oracle 12c:

```
create table t1 (
    id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1),
    info VARCHAR2(10)
    );
```